# Unable to add json string to a url with special character. Illegal character exception

Tags: json, web-services

I have a situation here, where i need to make a webservice call. I have a url and some parameters needs to be added to this url. These parameters have a start date and an end date which needs to be sent. So i parse this with JSON and create a url.

needed url:
http://somelink.com/somemethod?param={"startingAT":"2013-04-23","endingAT":"2013-04-30"}

When I execute this url using WebResource, like:
WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);
ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json")    .get(ClientResponse.class);
String output = response.getEntity(String.class);

I have made a JSON string for the parameter which is : {"startingAT":"2013-04-23","endingAT":"2013-04-30"} i.e. exactly the same as what I need.

When I execute this url, i get an illegal character exception. Please Help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode the JSON string first, using URLEncoder.encode().

Of course, a better alternative would be to use URL encoding instead of JSON, for example:

```
http://somelink.com/somemethod?start=2013-04-23&end=2013-04-30
```

Or even better if the /somemethod handler supports it, send it through a POST request.

Comment: my url for WS needs quoted string

Comment: Okay then try encoding it. The quotes will get encoded as %22 and should be received okay by the server.